# Is it correct/appropriate to write a word using katakana and hiragana at the same time?

Tags: katakana, orthography, hiragana

For example:

I noticed what the name of the game Nekopara (ネコぱら) is half-written using katakana(ネコ - neko) and half-written using hiragana(ぱら - para). I'm wondering why so. Сould you explain this to me? Maybe I'm wrong about something, I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be accepted. For example, あずきバー, なでしこジャパン and いちごミルク, though there may not be many and it may not be accepted for formal names. Only the author knows why he wrote the name like that.

Generally, katakana is used for loan‐words and onomatopoeic words, and we feel more affinity and softness for hiragana than kanji.

Names of animals and plants are generally written in katakana in the case of academic names.